# Does each menorah need its own shamash

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, chanuka, menora-chanukia

I understand that I need a shamosh for my menorah
Do I need 2 shamoshes  if 2 people light 2 menorahs next to each other

Sources please

Comment: Why do you understand that you need a shamash?

Comment: People use "_shamash_" to refer to an extra light sitting near (or attached to) a _m'nora_. People also use it to refer to a candle used to light the _m'nora_. Which do you mean? This question is unclear to me. (cc @DoubleAA )

Comment: @msh210 i guess the first one

Comment: Then edit that in to your question for clarity.

Comment: My understanding i sthat there is no requirement that the shamash even stay there as part of teh menorah, itself. I have ot seen any source mentioning thsi - only one that you may not use the other candles for lighting each other. If this is true, I wonder why almost all menorot have a spot for the shamash, anyway. I've seen people blow out the shamash after the other candles are lit, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mishna Berura 673:18](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=286) says that so long that each Menora is in a separate place, each one should have a Shamash. From this I would deduce that if all the Menoras are being lit in the same area, only one Shamash is necessary.

However Be'air Hataiv 5 seems to say that all those who light need a Shamash. Be'air Hataiv seems to mention that the Rashal is lenient regarding this.